# JPA Eclipselink - Multitenant - TenantDiscriminatorColumn as primaryKey - can't execute a POST request

Tags: java, jpa, odata, multi-tenant, postman

i red a lot of helpful answers here and I hope you can help me with my problem too.

**Scenario:**

I created a JaveEE dynamic web project with a servlet. 
Its an Application Managed Persistence Project. Like this -> https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?e4aeacd2bb5710148ee99255136d96a5.html

Database runs on Hana Cloud Platform with a trial account.

I used an **@IdClass** Annotation for an composite primary key and marked **firstname** and **lastname** as Id. 
I annotated the class with **@Multitenant** and **@TenantDiscriminatorColumn**
and my primary key has 3 values -> tenant_id, firstname and lastname.

I also defined some OData Services with JPAEdmExtension to access the data with an OData request.

And now here is my Problem: When i fire GET requests with chromes postman. it works well but when i try POST requests there is no entry in my database even though postman  says 201: created

I guess postman cannot handle the tenant_id column which is a tenantDiscriminatorColumn and not visible in http requests?

But how can i solve this problem? I need to access the Data with OData and also hiding the tenant_id.

thanks for reply.

**Code Attachment:**

Class Person:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PersonPK.class)
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(length = 36, primaryKey = true)
@NamedQuery(name = "AllPersons", query = "select p from Person p")
public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
private String firstname;

@Id
@Column(name = "LASTNAME")
private String lastname;

//...getter setter constructor
}
```

Class PersonPK:

```
public class PersonPK implements Serializable {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;

public PersonPK() { }

public PersonPK(String firstname, String lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

//..getter + hashcode / equals override
}
```

Class PersonProcessing which provides entity data model:

```
public class PersonProcessing implements JPAEdmExtension {

@Override
public void extendJPAEdmSchema(JPAEdmSchemaView view) {
    Schema edmSchema = view.getEdmSchema();
    List<EntityType> entityTypes= edmSchema.getEntityTypes();
    for (Iterator<EntityType> iterator = entityTypes.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        EntityType et = (EntityType) iterator.next();
        if (et.getName().equals("Person")) {
            List<Property> props = et.getProperties();
            }
        }
    }
}    
}
```

Tenantid is provided by a resource ref in the web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>TenantContext</res-ref-name>
<res-type>com.sap.cloud.account.TenantContext</res-type>
</resource-ref>
```

Get and Post requests with postman

```
//..hanatrial.../personApplication/odata.svc/Persons
```

Comment: why not start by debugging your persistence code? and look at the JPA providers log.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the answer.  I had a problem with my JPA Procecssor implementation class. 
I didnt set the EntityManager with the TenantContext String.